# Using a custom layout with CheckedTextView for a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

To populate my `ListView`, I use an `ArrayAdapter<String>` which is declared like this :
`myListAdapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.myView,R.id.myTextView);`.
The xml file representing my view layout is :

```
<CheckedTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/DescriptionEtape"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/textCheckMark"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:checked="false"/>
```

To react to user's clicks, I have added :    `(ListView)FragmentView.findViewById(R.id.myListView)).setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View vue, int position, long id) {
                ((CheckedTextView)vue.findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).setChecked(!((CheckedTextView)vue.findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).isChecked());
            }
        });`
The `onItemClick` function is correctly executed when I touch an entry of the `ListView` and the corresponding entry is correctly checked. Unfortunately, another entry, which is not visible at the moment of the click, is checked as well!!!

What is wrong with my code?

According to Kintanpatel answer, with a `CheckedTextView` already embedded in a `LinearLayout`, I tried to use a custom `ArrayAdapter<String>`, with a `getView` function looking like this :

```
    public View getView(int position,View container,ViewGroup parent){
    View view;

    view= super.getView(position,container,parent);
    ((CheckedTextView)vue.findViewById(R.id.myTextView)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((CheckedTextView)v).setChecked(!((CheckedTextView)v).isChecked());
        }
    });

    return(view);
}
```

And I still have the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, after having looked at the xml file describing the `simple_list_item_checked`, I noticed that there was no `LinearLayout`. I suppressed it from my own xml file and everything is now fine!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use BaseAdapter insted of ArrayAdapter.
you only need to create Simple class and exteds with BaseAdapter,also create custom cell in layout and last apply this adapter to ListvView.
You can perform all functionality  with custom cell.
below i create sample for You.

lay_cell.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CheckBox" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MyAdapter.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;

/**
 * Created by sai on 14-Jul-16.
 */
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 10;//return how many cell you want to create
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.lay_cell, parent, false);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and don't forget to apply this adpter to ListView,

```
listview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(context));
```

Comment: My `CheckedTextView` was already embedded in a `LinearLayout`. I have tried to use a custom class based on `ArrayAdapter<String>` and to use the code you provided me in the `getView` to register an `OnClikListener` to my `CheckedTextView`. No improvement... Question updated.